# How to Change keyboard layout but keep shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have recently switched to the [Workman](http://www.workmanlayout.com/blog/) keyboard layout, I use auto-hotkey to map some keys back to ctrl-c ctrl-v as I really can't get used to that shift.

However on my home computer no mapping was necessary - it seems that whenever I hit ctrl it switches back to qwerty for that shortcut. This is actually extremely useful as all my shortcuts in Visual Studio etc remain the same, but I have NO IDEA how I managed to make this occur.

Windows 7 at home, Windows 8 here at work, different keyboard drivers as I had installed Workman at home yonks ago.

Does anyone know how I can acheive the "ctrl = qwerty else workman" behavior I see at home?

Comment: Found another thread which puts forward some solutions: http://superuser.com/questions/10980/is-there-a-way-to-use-dvorak-keyboard-layout-but-with-command-keys-mapped-to-qw